# Nodeselector for os linux for fluxcd doesn't get applied in Helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am working with a Kubernetes environment with mixed worker nodes (Linux and windows).

I try to deploy fluxcd with the helm chart as explained at https://github.com/fluxcd/flux

The command I use:

```
helm upgrade -i flux fluxcd/flux --wait --namespace fluxcd --set git.url=${GHREPO} --set-file ssh.known_hosts=/home/${USER}/work/DevOps/flux/known_hosts --set git.user=${GHUSER} --set git.email="testqmail.com"
```

Expectation in the deployment of fluxcd the [nodeselector](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/blob/master/docs/tutorials/get-started.md) is available.

But the deployment in kubernetes **does not** contain the nodeselector:

```
...
      nodeSelector: 
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux    
...
```

and therefore the Kubernetes scheduler runs it on a windows node which of course fails

Workaround possible with kubectl patch deployment but how do I do this with helm in a correct way?

Comment: Can you share your deployment yaml before the kubectl patch?

Comment: Do you have label `beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux` assigned to your node?

Comment: You can find the deployment at https://github.com/Staudenmaier/k8s/blob/master/k8s-docker-ui/charts/templates/deployment.yaml

Comment: Yes after double checking with "kubectl describe nodes dev-worker1" the label `beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux` exists

Comment: Did you restart kube-scheduler after deployment?

Comment: yes I did, but  doesn't help.

Comment: @Klaus could you provide helm get values flux?